# tvOS Siri remote: SKView UITapGestureRecognizer not working, but UISwipeGestureRecognizer works fine

Tags: uitapgesturerecognizer, skview, siri-remote, tvos13

I am using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on an `SKView` to detect taps on the Siri remote (tvOS).

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognized:)];
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPressTypeUpArrow]];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

The taps never get recognized, the selector is never called. However when I use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, everything works fine. I change nothing else.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognized:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
swipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
```

So, swipes DO work, taps DON'T work on an `SKView`. To fix it, I need to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the parent `UIView` of the SKView.

Any ideas as to why the taps won't work on an `SKView`?

Comment: GestureRecognizers has the States. If your view has the multiple gestureRecognizers, there is a chance of going a gesture to an invalid state..Selector won't be if the state is in invalid.

Comment: @ApparaoMulpuri sorry I was editing the question for a long time. The view has no other gesture recognizers.